# How str_replace value in json?

Tags: php, json, replace, str-replace

could somebody help me with str_replace value in json file, please?
My code working well on replace string, but it dosnt working on value in json.

Working well to replace correctly "old" with "new" in all json files:

```
foreach(glob('*.json') as $path_to_file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file); 
    $file_contents = str_replace('old','new',$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
```

But when I need replace `"min_order":""` with `"min_order":"1"` it doesn't work. I can not replace `""` with `"1"` directly, because I have in json many other values.

I tested this code, but it didn't work:

```
foreach(glob('*.json') as $path_to_file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace('"min_order":""','"min_order":"1"',$file_contents);
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
```

Can somebody help me with this issue please?

Thank you in advance.
Jiri

Comment: Convert it to an array before. Don't try to edit the json string!

Comment: Using `str_replace()` on a JSON string can cause all sorts of issues and I would have thought it was the last thing you would want to do. `"min_order":""` may be present as `"min_order" : ""` or `"min_order": ""`, so it will fail for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you do `$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);`

you should then use `json_decode($file_contents);` to convert the json string to array or object,

then manipulate the array/object by replacing THERE the value of the key you need to replace,

and then use on that modified array `json_encode();` to convert the array/object back to JSON format

and finally `file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);`

**Using str_replace on json format is possible within JSON but is not advisable, nor is practical.**

Comment: Note that if you don't know the paths where the values you want to change are located, it's more handy to convert the json to a multidimensional array and then to search the values with `array_walk_recursive`.